# Pytorch inconsistent size with pad_packed_sequence, seq2seq

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, seq2seq

I'm having some inconsistencies with the output of a encoder I got from this [github](https://github.com/kaituoxu/Listen-Attend-Spell/blob/master/src/models/encoder.py) .

The encoder looks as follows:

```py
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    r"""Applies a multi-layer LSTM to an variable length input sequence.
    """

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers,
                 dropout=0.0, bidirectional=True, rnn_type='lstm'):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = 40
        self.hidden_size = 512
        self.num_layers = 8
        self.bidirectional = True
        self.rnn_type = 'lstm'
        self.dropout = 0.0
        if self.rnn_type == 'lstm':
            self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers,
                               batch_first=True,
                               dropout=dropout,
                               bidirectional=bidirectional)

    def forward(self, padded_input, input_lengths):
        """
        Args:
            padded_input: N x T x D
            input_lengths: N
        Returns: output, hidden
            - **output**: N x T x H
            - **hidden**: (num_layers * num_directions) x N x H
        """
        total_length = padded_input.size(1)  # get the max sequence length
        packed_input = pack_padded_sequence(padded_input, input_lengths,
                                            batch_first=True,enforce_sorted=False)
        packed_output, hidden = self.rnn(packed_input)
        pdb.set_trace()
        output, _ = pad_packed_sequence(packed_output, batch_first=True, total_length=total_length)
        return output, hidden
```

So it only consists of a rnn lstm cell, if I print the encoder this is the output:

```py
LSTM(40, 512, num_layers=8, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
```

So it should have a 512 sized output right? But when I feed a tensor with size `torch.Size([16, 1025, 40])` 16 samples of 1025 vectors with size 40 (that gets packed to fit the RNN) the output that I get from the RNN has a new encoded size of 1024 `torch.Size([16, 1025, 1024])` when it should have been encoded to 512 right?

Is there something Im missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `bidirectional=True` makes the LSTM bidirectional, which means there will be two LSTMs, one that goes from left to right and the other that goes from right to left.

From the [`nn.LSTM` documentation - Outputs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM):

> - **output** of shape *(seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size)*: tensor containing the output features *(h_t)* from the last layer of the LSTM, for each *t*. If a `torch.nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence` has been given as the input, the output will also be a packed sequence.
>
>   For the unpacked case, the directions can be separated using `output.view(seq_len, batch, num_directions, hidden_size)`, with forward and backward being direction 0 and 1 respectively. Similarly, the directions can be separated in the packed case.

Your output has the size `[batch, seq_len, 2 * hidden_size]` (`batch` and `seq_len` are swapped in your case due to setting `batch_first=True`) because of using a bidirectional LSTM. The outputs of the two are concatenated in order to have the information of both, which you could easily separate if you wanted to treat them differently.